# Upgrading from react router v5 to v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, electron, react-router-dom

Following this [tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbwE-txeBNw&list=PL-LDQE9x9hLyowrXuGkk53uVPbljucpdK&index=60) to try to build a simple React, Electron, and firebase app.

This project mirrors this [demo](https://github.com/mikewesthad/FA20-CodeSprint-Code/tree/master/Code%20Sprint%20C/Week%2004/electron-react-firebase-demo-solution) project. I'm getting a lot of compile errors, mostly outdated content and dependencies, but managed to fix most of them up. The main thing I'm struggling with now is upgrading some code from `react-router` v5 to v6, specifically in `app.js`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Router, Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import AddMoviePage from "../pages/add-movie-page";
import EditMoviePage from "../pages/edit-movie-page";
import AccountPage from "../pages/account-page";
import MoviesPage from "../pages/movies-page";
import NotFoundPage from "../pages/not-found-page";
import { auth } from "../data/firebase";
import Nav from "./nav";
import { createMemoryHistory } from "history";

function AuthenticatedRoute(props) {
  const { isAuthenticated, children, ...routeProps } = props;
  return <Route {...routeProps}>{isAuthenticated ? children : <Navigate to="/account" />}</Route>;
}

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const isAuthenticated = user !== null;

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((currentUser) => {
      setUser(currentUser);
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const history = createMemoryHistory();
  console.log(history);


  return (
  <Router history={history}>
      <Nav user={user} />

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/account">
          <AccountPage user={user} />
        </Route>

        <AuthenticatedRoute path="/" exact isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}>
          <MoviesPage user={user} />
        </AuthenticatedRoute>

        <AuthenticatedRoute path="/add" isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}>
          <AddMoviePage user={user} />
        </AuthenticatedRoute>

        <AuthenticatedRoute path="/edit/:id" isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}>
          <EditMoviePage user={user} />
        </AuthenticatedRoute>

        <Route path="*">
          <NotFoundPage />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm getting the following error and can't really figure out what's going on:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

The above error occurred in the `<Router>` component.

Comment: Have you tried [the documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5) ?

Answer (score 1):

## Issues

The main issue here is that you are importing and using the low-level [`Router`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/router) component instead of one of the high-level routers (*i.e. `BrowserRouter`, `MemoryRouter`, `HashRouter`, etc*). The `Router` component has a couple ***required*** props and `history` isn't one of them.

Router Interface:

> ```
> declare function Router(
>   props: RouterProps
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
>
> interface RouterProps {
>   basename?: string;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   location: Partial<Location> | string; // <-- required!
>   navigationType?: NavigationType;
>   navigator: Navigator; // <-- required!
>   static?: boolean;
> }
> ```

The high-level routers all instantiate/manage a history reference internally and pass the required props and render the base `Router`.

Additional issues found in the code:

1. Another issue is that in `react-router-dom@6` custom route components are no longer valid. Only `Route` components can be rendered by the `Routes` component. You'll instead convert your older v5 custom route components, a.k.a. `AuthenticatedRoute`, either into Wrapper components that render the `children` prop, or as the preferred method a [Layout Route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes).
2. A final related issue is that `Route` components and only be rendered by the `Routes` component or other `Route` components in the case of building nested routes. In other words, the only valid children components of a `Route` component is another `Route` component. The routed content you want to be rendered on a route is passed to the `Route` component's [`element`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#element) prop.

## Solution

Convert `AuthenticatedRoute` to a layout route.

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

function AuthenticatedRoute({ isAuthenticated }) {
  if (isAuthenticated === undefined) {
    // Don't render the protected content or redirect until we confirm
    // authentication status.
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }
  return isAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/account" replace />;
}
```

It seems you are wanting to really use a `MemoryRouter` since you are instantiating your own `MemoryHistory` object. Import and render the `MemoryRouter` directly. Move the route "children" onto their respective route's `element` prop.

Example:

```
...
import {
  MemoryRouter as Router, // <-- import high-level router
  Routes,
  Route,
  Navigate,
  Outlet
} from "react-router-dom";
...

function AuthenticatedRoute({ isAuthenticated }) {
  if (isAuthenticated === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }
  return isAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/account" replace />;
}

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(); // <-- initially not auth'd or unauth'd

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((currentUser) => {
      setUser(currentUser); // <-- sets to user object or null
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router> // <-- Now really a MemoryRouter
      <Nav user={user} />

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/account" element={<AccountPage user={user} />} />

        <Route element={<AuthenticatedRoute isAuthenticated={user} />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<MoviesPage user={user} />} />
          <Route path="/add" element={<AddMoviePage user={user} />} />
          <Route path="/edit/:id" element={<EditMoviePage user={user} />} />
        </Route>

        <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```